# PHP Twitteroauth reset_time_in_seconds convert to a datetime

Tags: php, datetime, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using the twitteroauth library found here: [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). One of the connection methods is to retrieve the rate limit. One of the returning values it contains is: `[reset_time_in_seconds] => 1365270026`. How do I convert this to a PHP datetime value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a UNIX timestamp, so you can use [`DateTime::setTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php):

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->setTimestamp( 1365270026);
```

Then, you can format it however you want:

```
echo $date->format( 'F jS Y, h:i:sA');
```